# 400 BAD Request Error while calling GraphQL endpoint using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, resttemplate

I am trying to call a public graphql API using RestTemplate in Springboot. It seems there is some problem how the request is being sent as I am getting *HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request*.

I tried to send the content-type in headers in different format but greeted with different errors :

**Content-type as APPLICATION_GRAPHQL :**

```
public class GetRespPayLoad {

    private final String url = "https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql";

    public void getPayload(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_GRAPHQL);

        String query = "{\n" +
                "  country(code: \"BR\") {\n" +
                "    name\n" +
                "    native\n" +
                "    capital\n" +
                "    emoji\n" +
                "    currency\n" +
                "    languages {\n" +
                "      code\n" +
                "      name\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }";

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(query, headers), String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

**Error :**

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys."

**Content-type as APPLICATION_JSON :**

```
public class GetRespPayLoad {

    private final String url = "https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql";

    public void getPayload(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        String query = "query Query {\n" +
                "  country(code: \"BR\") {\n" +
                "    name\n" +
                "    native\n" +
                "    capital\n" +
                "    emoji\n" +
                "    currency\n" +
                "    languages {\n" +
                "      code\n" +
                "      name\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(query, headers), String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

**Error : **

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "Error

```
Bad Request
```

"

Comment: Why do you need to trigger a post request?, Isn't a get request more appropriate here as your aim is to just fetch the data? However, the error clearly mentions that a body is missing for the post request, which means you have to pass an empty string as body if you are continuing to use post

Comment: i got this error too. but in postman when i set request body type to qraphql instead of raw it works.